# Add github javascript library (underline.js) to my project

Tags: javascript

I want to underline my text and therefore add a javascript library from github in my webpage. I know there are other options to underline text, but I wnat to use this beautiful underlining of that library. Also, disregarding the underline problem, I just would like to know how to use such a github project. I want to add this library: https://github.com/wentin/underlineJS

I already added libraries before, but there was always a npm install comment provided or a .jar file was in the github main folder that you could use (in Java, not Javascript)

From looking at the code in the github project, I think I have to at least add this script link to my header:

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/underline.css" />
```

then add this to my CSS:

```
.underline {
position: relative;
}
.underline span {
 pointer-events: none;

}
.underline canvas {
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.1);*/
  /*z-index: -1;*/
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -o-user-select: none; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and finally use this in my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="underline">at your gate</a>
<br>
<br>
```

But this had absolutely no effect....

Comment: _"I want to underline my text and therefore add a javascript library from github"_ - You really don't need JavaScript to "underline" text. Use CSS and `text-decoration: underline`.

Comment: @Andreas this lib seems to be a polyfill for features unsupported by css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add this library easily, because it is just a tech demo.

Quote:

> Despite the catchy name, Underline.js is a tech demo only. That means you won’t be able to drop it into any projects without modifying it a whole bunch first.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/#underline-js-canvas